# Are there any currently studied or hypothesized crewed Mars missions that utilize the Space Launch System?

Tags: mars, nasa, crewed-spaceflight, deep-space, sls

Space Launch System is finally beginning to see the light at the end of the tunnel. If everything goes smoothly (fingers crossed!), we should see the Artemis program kicked into full drive by the end of the decade. Post (or even during) Artemis, are there any studied, planned, or theoretical crewed martian missions that utilize the Space Launch System Architecture?

Comment: Mars missions are ostensibly part of the rationale for the Gateway station, does that count? Pretty much any beyond-LEO effort proposed today is going to involve the SLS purely for political reasons, though its low launch rate will realistically limit its role. (Again, look at Gateway...two modules of which are now being launched together on a Falcon Heavy instead of on two SLS/Orion flighs.)

Comment: It would not be practical to use SLS for a crewed Mars mission. The very low launch rate will prevent it from lifting sufficient tonnage to be useful. If (or more likely when) Starship becomes operational SLS will be obsolete. It might continue for years for political (jobs) reasons, but it would only be able to make a token effort in any such Mars project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's always plenty of studies.

NASA Mars architecture presentations always use SLS. There's a diversity of them, from the DRM that Fred mentions, to the [variations](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20210017131), to the [bat**** crazy](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20210021084/downloads/A%20Common%20Habitat%20Deep%20Space%20Exploration%20Vehicle%20for%20Transit%20and%20Orbital%20Operations.pdf). There's more of course; this [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Antrs.nasa.gov+%22sls%22+%22mars+architecture%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enAU934AU934&sxsrf=AOaemvIHT4DSlZ4eFUKVRXu2Z5irZAwqPA%3A1640003225412&ei=mXbAYYuqGKeX4-EPpNSQqAo&ved=0ahUKEwjL2riNsPL0AhWnyzgGHSQqBKUQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=site%3Antrs.nasa.gov+%22sls%22+%22mars+architecture%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQiQFYlhJg4xNoAXAAeACAAeMBiAGeEpIBBjAuMTMuMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) will provide reading to your fatigue. The architecture that Boeing [likes](https://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/space/space_launch_system/source/space-launch-system-flip-book-040821.pdf) is the [Deep Space Transport SEP setup](https://nvite.jsc.nasa.gov/presentations/b2/D1_Mars_Connolly.pdf). Aerojet Rocketdyne of course has a couple of studies/presentations on the topic; focussing in on [NTP](http://fiso.spiritastro.net/telecon/Kokan-Joyner_6-3-20/) and the [DST SEP](https://rocket.com/sites/default/files/documents/CubeSat/SustainableConceptHumanExplorationSpacecraft.pdf) setup.

There are also [presentations](https://www.exploremars.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/0915_1000_HPrice_Mars-Orbital-Mission-2033.pdf) like these from JPL Lads at [ExploreMars](https://www.exploremars.org) sessions about pure chem architectures.
[image: Think about what you've done and go sit in the corner. 4 SLS launches and 11 CLV to spend 30 days in Mars orbit for a total mission duration of 570 days.]

^this image would likely give Robert Zubrin a heart attack.

With that I supposed we should also consider [OG Mars Direct](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/376589main_04%20-%20Mars%20Direct%20Power%20Point-7-30-09.pdf), which baselined a vehicle similar to modern Day SLS, with it's 2 launch chem-ISRU approach. Zubrin has since [moved on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xN1rqhRSTE) however.

The crux of SLS use cases in these architectures is to launch Orion or large elements; with refuelling/tug stages being given to CLV. Given that [2033](https://www.ida.org/-/media/feature/publications/e/ev/evaluation-of-a-human-mission-to-mars-by-2033/d-10510.ashx) is out for a DST setup and that [2039](https://www.nap.edu/catalog/25977/space-nuclear-propulsion-for-human-mars-exploration) is about the earliest for NASA humans to Mars assuming conventional means, by which point SLS's future is looking dodgy; eh...

Comment: I was actually in a room with Robert Zubrin when this was presented. Can confirm that he did not have a heart attack;-) It's still a bit silly, but...

Comment: Your "2033" link to ida.org is giving me "Access denied". Is that some classified info that I'm not supposed to see as a non-American, or just a broken link?

Comment: @TooTea This link should be better; https://www.ida.org/idamedia/Corporate/Files/Publications/STPIPubs/2019/D-10510.pdf      and if not just download it from here;
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/922737781237768202/922737871356559440/Evaluation_of_Humans_to_Mars_in_2033.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are.

NASA has a long running series of studies for a Human Mars Mission.   These have traditionally been referred to as Design Reference Missions (DRM).   A good summary of all the DRMs can be found here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Design_Reference_Mission

The very latest [addendum to the DRM 5](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/NASA-SP-2009-566-ADD2.pdf) mentions SLS 322 times.